# Nested $http calls $q.all returns promises but not resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I call a function that returns a list with ID that i want to use in chained call. Everything seems to work until i want to read all those objects that are returned.. Those are promises but i cannot find out why i cannot resolve them.

```
        //Get bubbles and then it calls another function getBubbleMessage with result from previous and last getBubbleMessage returns an array of promises. 

   $scope.loadStartPage = function () {

        $scope.getBubblesThatUserHasAccessTo().then($scope.getBubbleMessage).then(function (data) {
            $log.info("INFO:: " + data);
            $scope.bubblesWithMessages = data;


        });
    };

    $scope.getBubblesThatUserHasAccessTo = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        BubblesService.getBubblesUserAccess().then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);

        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

This function is gettings some things that we need to resolve messages connected to those id:s that above service is returning

```
    $scope.getBubblesThatUserHasAccessTo = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        BubblesService.getBubblesUserAccess().then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);

        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

This function get alls messages and returns promise objects - and these i cannot resolve??

```
    $scope.getBubbleMessage = function (data) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promises = [];

        angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
            $log.info("DDD" + item.name);
            var promise = BubblesService.getBubbleMessages(item.id, 0, 1);
            promises.push(promise);
        });

        //return $q.all([promises]);
        $q.all([promises]).then(function (result) {
            $log.info(result);
            return result[0];

        });

    };
```

Above function returns an array of 60 objects..
[image]

In the end i want to have a new object that i use in my ng-repeat on page. I really think this is something todo that im new to angular and promises.... but after a couple of hours of trying to fix this i really need help :)

Comment: It should be `return $q.all([promises]);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$q.all takes an array of promise. Here, you are doing $q.all([myPromises]), which resolve instantly, because '[myPromise]' is an array and not a promise (you give an array parameter with first and only element is an array of promise when you should simply use the promise array. So [] and not [[]]). Second issue : you are not returning this promise in the parent function.

You should simply change the block

```
$q.all([promises]).then(function (result) {
            $log.info(result);
            return result[0];

        });
```

with

```
return $q.all(promises);
```

Which will resolve with an array of resolved for each promise in the array.

Comment: That i tried and it seems to work BUT - i cannot understand how to access those objects after that. in my method. How can i see how they are structured? 

$scope.bubblesWithMessages = data; ??

Is there a way to see how data look like?

Comment: simply $scope.bubblesWithMessages = data; Yep, data being an array of message

Comment: console.log(data) ? {{bubblesWithMessages | json}} ? what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: I done a JSON.stringify på data object and get this.

[[{"$$state":{"status":0}},{"$$state":{"status":0}},{"$$state":{"status":0}},{"$$state":{"status":0}},{"$$state":{"status":0}},{"$$state":{"status":0}},

Comment: can you show the content of you BubblesService.getBubbleMessages method ?

Comment: and DID you remove the [] on your $q.all call ? your comment make the think the opposite. $q.all(promises), NOT $q.all([promises]) ?

Comment: How do you mean that im not returning promise in parent object?

Comment: AHHH :) No i getting somewhere... i removed []! :)

Comment: yep. angular's $q.all and jquery's $.when are not accepting the same paremeters format, if you're coming from jquery ;)

Comment: Im going to test some and get back to you! :) Thank you for the moment! :)

Comment: Thank you it did work out well! So hard sometimes to find errors! Glad you helped me! :)